# Redirect to Action-Controller MVC 4 inside Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need a little help with this since I am very new to AJAX in general.  In a given page that I have (a view) I display a button which brings up a form. What I ultimately want is to pass the data input in that form to a controller inside my application. I know there are plenty of tutorials on how to do it out there...however, I seem to have a problem understanding how this is done; therefore, I want to traverse this step-by-step.  I just simply want to display a different view after the user clicks on the "Save" button on the dialog.  I hope that is clear.  Here is my HTML + jQuery

```
@model AccommodationEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "List", "Accommodation")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>    
            @if ( Model.Accommodation.LocaleID != Guid.Empty)
            {
                @Html.DisplayAccommodation(IAccommodationDisplay);
            }
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>

<div class="genericform">
<form id="form" method="post">

    @Html.AccommodationEditDisplay()
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add New Address", "", "", new { id = "addaddresses" }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
    @if (Model != null && Model.Accommodation.Addresses.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                This Locale Contains No Addresses
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Address address in Model.Accommodation.Addresses)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @address.Address1
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
<br /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Save"  />
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Delete" />
</form>
</div>

<button id="opener">Add Address</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Add Address" style="display:none;">
<label for="Address1">Address: </label><input id="Address1" />
<label for="Address2">Address 2: </label><input id="Address2" /> 
<label for="City">City: </label><input id="City" />
<label for="State">State: </label><input id="State" />
<label for="PostalCode">Postal Code: </label><input id="PostalCode" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet"  />

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 250
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 250
            },
            buttons: {
                "Save": {
                    text: "Save",
                    class: "",
                    click: function () {
                         //**redirect here**
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }},
                "Cancel": {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    class: "",
                    click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }},
            modal: true
        });

        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried using $.ajax({}) and setting this: `Url: "/Areas/Website/Controller/Action`
but scripting stops working at that point.
Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT**

Do I even need to use AJAX at all? I just want to pass the information in that form (inside the dialog) to a controller.

Comment: Please provide more detail on the view, such as the Html form (including the input button at the end, the one that says type="submit")

Comment: There is nothing special about the view. What I have in there are helpers to display an initial form. It doesn't have much to do with what I want to accomplish which is: display dialog, fill form, take that data typed into a controller, display that form with a ViewResult.  Does that make sense?

Comment: On the contrary, you do not actually need ajax or jquery etc etc. That's why I wanted you to show me your form, I can give you the steps on sending the data from your form to a controller. It's not terribly complex.

Comment: Give me one second, I'll update it

Comment: I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try replacing your `<form id="form" method="post"> form fields </form>` with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NameOfControllerMethod", "NameOfControllerClass")) 
{
<!-- fields for gathering data, your input fields essentially -->
}
```

**THEN** you need to go to your controller class, and add [HttpPost] above your controller method, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName(AccomodationEditViewModel viewModel) {
//do stuff in here with the viewModel, for example viewModel.Location, or viewModel.Name
}
```

**NOTE** that the [HttpPost] requires that you add a new "using" insert at the top of your controller class.

The NameOfControllerMethod is the method that has the HttpPost above it. The name of the controller class is like "MyClass", coming from the controller named MyClassController, as an example.

Comment: Thanks bro! Will try this in just one second.  I'll mark it as an answer as soon as I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I'm worried about is if your form inputs can be posted via the HttpPost, but the only way to find out is if you try it first :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.location = "/Areas/Website/Controller/Action";
```

inside your click function.

Comment: This is helpful as I see how javascript and jquery can interact...so that's the first step.  Now how would I be able to pass "data" (my form values) to this next page?

Comment: This jsfiddle should help.  I'm trying to do exactly what's going on there, display a dialog, get that data BUT, instead of appending it to a table in the same view, I want to call a controller action (to save the form in the database, etc..)  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/536fm/6/)

Comment: Ok so you have a view with a form, then you want to get the data from that form, pass it to a controller, and open another webpage (a view) essentially? Please show me your Html.BeginForm() etc etc

Comment: The form I want to submit is that in the dialog. I've updated my initial code to show the complete view, but the first form is strongly typed and not relevant for the purposes of what I want to accomplish.